# Iterator - java.util.NoSuchElementException in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, iterator

I have Java spring MVC application.

Through AngularJS. from I client I am uploading a single file and with some other data I am posting to server.

My Java Controller class

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void UploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println(request.getFileNames());
        Iterator<String> itr=request.getFileNames();
        System.out.println(itr.hashCode());
        MultipartFile file=request.getFile(itr.next());
        String fileName=file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(fileName);
          }
}
```

When I am running this I get first two lines printed and then getting exception.

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator@471164ef
1190767452
```

**Error**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:396)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:405)
    at com.uploaddemo.web.FileUploadController.UploadFile(DocumentUploadController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What it means? Is the server getting file or In the server Controller am I doing wrong?

Because when I print the hashcode of iterator, it gets printed and it means it is not null.(Correct me if I am wrong).

I am sending both file and other data from client.

Comment: try a `hasNext` before going for `next` on the iterator?

Comment: Even if iterator itself exists, it doesn't necessary mean, that there are objects to be iterated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is no file in your request. getFileNames will never return null: if there is no file, it's an iterator on an empty collection. To know if there is a file, you can call itr.hasNext().